# Obtener instancia de objeto a partir de parámetro

Tags: python, python-3.x

Es posible encontrar la instancia de un objeto de acuerdo a un parámetro bien definido.

```
class Viaje(object)
    def __init__(self, nombre, id_doc, lista):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.id_doc = id_doc
        self.contador = 0
        self.lista = []
```

A través de otra función que no pertenece a la clase y que no puedo modificar los argumentos, obtengo el `id_doc`

```
def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    print(doc_snapshot[0].to_dict()) #Obtención de id_doc   
    for doc in doc_snapshot:
        print(u'Cambio en el documento: {} de {}'.format(doc.id, doc.get('Nombre')))
        class_viaje.contador = class_viaje.contador+1
```

¿Existe alguna forma de recuperar la referencia a todo el objeto con el id obtenido, para poder trabajar manipular sus atributos?

Comment: Hola AGuzman, a ver si lo he entendido, ¿tienes varios objetos de la clase `Viajes` y quisieras buscar en ellos aquel con `in_doc` igual al recuperado de `doc`? Si es así ¿dónde o en que contenedor tienes las instancias de `Viaje`? ¿O es otra cosa?

Comment: Cierto, falto esa parte, disculpa.
```
for i in muse:
 doc = affected_doc.get() 
 class_viaje=Viaje(nombre, id_doc)
 class_viaje.iniciar_viaje()
 lista_usuarios.append(class_viaje)
```
Los objetos los creo a partir de un for, se crean tanto como me regresa la llamada a mi base de de datos. Siendo precisos, los objetos se guardan en una lista `lista_ususarios`

Answer (score 0):

Logré buscar el objeto que necesitaba con un parámetro, éste es el código.

```
def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    id_objeto = doc_snapshot[0].id
    objeto = next((x for x in lista if x.id_doc == id_objeto), None) #Asigna a `objeto` el objeto para manejar sus atributos. 
    for doc in doc_snapshot:
        print("Veces que se a modificado el documento de "+str(objeto.nombre) +" "+str(objeto.contador)+"\n")
```